# Display five numbers per line in Java

Tags: java

//I want to display all numbers divisible by 3 and 4 within a range entered by user and five numbers 
per line but my code doesn't work.I made a mistake in second for but I can't figure out.Please help me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter lowest value:");
    int lowest = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter upper value:");
    int upper = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = lowest; lowest <= upper; lowest++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ){
            if(lowest % 3 == 0 && lowest % 4 == 0){
                System.out.print(lowest + "  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for-loop to this:

```
for(int i = lowest; i <= upper; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5 && i <= upper; i++){
        if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 4 == 0){
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
            j++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

There were a few problems with your original code. `i` was never used, for instance. Also, because `i` was never incremented in the second for-loop, the same value would be printed 5 times.

Another thing to mention is that `i % 3 == 0 && i % 4 == 0` is equivalent to `i % 12 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using lowest, but not incremeting the value of lowest :). Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter lowest value:");
    int lowest = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter upper value:");
    int upper = input.nextInt();

    int printCount = 1;
    while(lowest <= upper){
        if(lowest % 3 == 0 && lowest % 4 == 0){
            System.out.print(lowest + "  "); //print a number divisible by 3,4
            if(printCount%5==0){
                System.out.println();        //when printCount reaches a multiple of 5 i.e. 5,10,15.., print a new line
            }
            printCount++;
        }
        lowest++;
    }
}
```